# A few questions about continuations and the continuation monad

Tags: category-theory, computer-science, lambda-calculus, monads

In Philip Wadler's ["Monads and composable continuations"](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Monads-and-Composable-Continuations-Wadler/3d2231608c7ba19935c610afd60f13bbe89d6b55) (published in Lisp and Symbolic Computation, 1994, [doi.org/10.1007/BF01019944](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01019944)) the following continuation monad is defined:

1. $type \hspace{0.2cm} M a = (a \rightarrow O) \rightarrow O$
2. $unit :: a \rightarrow M a$
3. $(\star) :: M a \rightarrow (a \rightarrow M b) \rightarrow M b$
4. $eval :: M O \rightarrow O$
5. $unit \hspace{0.2cm}  v = \lambda c. c v$
6. $m \star k = \lambda c.m (\lambda v. k v c)$
7. $eval \hspace{0.2cm} m = m \hspace{0.2cm}  id \hspace{0.5cm}[\text{where} \hspace{0.2cm} id = (\lambda v. v)]$

He then makes several claims in the passage below:

> Here $O$ is the type of answers...
>
> We have added one extra operation, $eval$, to the monad, which can be used
>   to extract the answer from a ‘top-level’ computation.
>   Substituting these definitions of $unit$ and $\star$ into the call-by-value monad
>   translation and simplifying yields the usual call-by-value continuation-passing style translation. A pleasant property of this translation is that
>   a source program is always given the same call-by-value semantics, regardless of whether the target program is given a call-by-value or call-by-name
>   semantics.
>
> Monads are in a sense just an abstraction of continuation passing style,
>   and the second argument to $\star$ is very similar to a continuation. In a sense,
>   we have continuations at two levels: at the meta-level, we have the continuation $k :: a \rightarrow M b$ and at the object level we have the continuation $c :: a \rightarrow O$.

Here are my questions:

- What does he mean by the type of 'answers' and in what sense $eval$ extracts answers?
- What does he mean by the "usual call-by-value continuation-passing style translation" and so what 'pleasant property' is he attributing to this translation?
- What does he mean when he says that "Monads are in a sense just an abstraction of continuation passing style,
  and the second argument to $\star$ is very similar to a continuation"?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style might give some useful background for understanding the paper.

Comment: As I have said in another recent question, I find the stuff on the internet on continuations and continuation passing not very helpful, since I don't know programming at all. Very rarely are any pure examples from the lambda calculus given.

Comment: Perhaps the best move would be to start becoming familiar with programming. If you are not interested in that, then I'm not really sure why you are interested in these topics. They do have connections to other areas of mathematics, but either those other areas have their own approach to the topics, or, for better or worse, the topics aren't commonly used.

Comment: I don't have enough time to do that properly, so whilst your advice may be correct, it can't help with my current problem. My research is on the semantics of natural language, where monads have become relevant. Understanding papers on these topics is important. If you can help I would be happy :)

Comment: So why not read papers about [monads in linguistics](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monad+%28in+linguistics%29) or *mathematical* papers about category theory, the field where monads originate? Philip Wadler's target audience is functional programmers. There are papers on applying monads to differential equations too, for example, but reading them won't be particularly helpful for applications in linguistics. I'm not sure how reading a paper defining something you don't yet understand in terms of something else you don't yet understand is helpful or an efficient use of time.

Comment: I happen to be one of the authors of certain papers on monads in linguistics, so I certainly don't need to read such papers (and you certainly don't need to tell me that!). I just don't understand the programming jargon, but have more of a grip on the category theory definition. if you had read the papers on monads in linguistics, you would see they constantly cite Wadler. So are you able to help now? I presume you do know one or two things about this area.

Answer (score 1):

1. I think $O$ stands for '*Output*', the set for possible outputs (or answers) of a 'program'. 
   We can regard functions of the form $X\to O$ as 'programs'. 
   Now, being of type $MA$ means that it is a program that inputs a program that inputs an object of type $A$. Let's call these 'computations' *program analyser* programs for now. 
   The unit of this monad $M$ assigns the 'evalutaion at $a$' function $\lambda f.fa$ to an object $a::A$. So that it is indeed of the form $A\to MA$. 
   The $eval$ function explicitly evaluates the identity function $id::O\to O$ at its input $m::MO$. Elements of $MO$ are program analysers for programs of input type $O$, which can be seen as the 'top level' computations, because they are 'postprocessing' the output.
2. The [continuation passing style translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style) is a translation of programs that basically gets rid of returns, and thus get closer to the machine code order. The direct programming style is to use embedded function calls with return values. Take an example:

   > def f(x):
   >   $\ $ return x*2 
   >   def g(x): 
   >   $\ $ return x+1 
   >   **print( f(g(20)) )**

   In the continuation style, instead of returns there's always a next call of a function, which has to be given as (the last) parameter in each and every function, including the basic operations. Supposed we have such basic operations $\ $+(a,b,k) :=k(a+b)$\ $ and $\ \ast$(a,b,k) :=k(a*b)$\ $,  the previous example translates to something like:

   > def f(x,k):
   >   $\ $ $\ast$(x,2,k)
   >   def g(x,k):
   >   $\ $ +(x,1,k)
   >   **g(20, $\lambda$x. f(x, print) )**

   Here $x$ will hold the result of application of $g$ to $20$.
3. Simply because this *continuation monad* $M$ is a specific example of monads, the monads can be viewed as abstractions of this. 
   Point 6. in definition of $M$ illustrates the continuation behavior.

Comment: Thanks :). I don't fully understand a few points. Could we possibly have a discussion in chat?

Comment: Yes. How to get there?

Comment: Ah, apparently you can't move comments from the main site to chat if the automatic mechanism is not triggered. I'll just ask you some questions here. You say the unit of this monad M assigns the 'evaluation at a' function λf.fa to an object a::A. So is f in λf.fa of type A→MA (taking a::A as its argument)? But if so, isn't $λf_{A→MA}.fa$, a function from f to propositions or truth values (given the dot)? Also, is MO := (O → O) →O, and so MO → O is ((O → O) →O ) → O). Since unit gives the converse of MO → O, don't we get a collapse of the monad? (i.e, MO iff O)

Comment: I ask partly, because this collapse is discussed on page 4 here https://www.uni-bamberg.de/fileadmin/uni/fakultaeten/wiai_professuren/grundlagen_informatik/papersMM/pll.pdf     for a 'monad'-based logic

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by saying in the underlined part here: "Elements of MO are program analysers for programs of input type O, $\underline{\text{which can be seen as the 'top level' computations, because they are 'postprocessing' the output.}}$

Comment: In your example of continuation passing style, I understand every part except for the final line $g(20, λx. f(x, print) )$. Why, just like the other lines, isn't this $print( f(g(20)), k)$ with k as the extra parameter to the function? Finally you mention that continuation passing style gets closer to the machine code order. What do you mean by this precisely? What exactly are the advantages of continuation passing style? Thanks for your answers, by the way, I just am quite unfamiliar with programming.

Comment: Rather, follow this link directly: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73570/continuation-of-talking-about-continuation-monad

Comment: Just answer here about the last line: The order of the operations we would perform in this case is to apply $g$ to the constant $20$, *then* apply $f$ to its result, *then* print it out. Note that continuation style produces exactly this order, reading from left to right. Also, now $g$ takes two arguments, so you can't call $g(20)$ - you have to put a continuation function as the last argument in each and every function call.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73580/discussion-between-user65526-and-berci).